# Appending various div elements if variable is an empty string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm building an admin panel from scratch for a personal project, one of the tasks I want it to do is show data in a table, in order to get this data I use AJAX and jQuery to grab data from the server and populate the table in the front-end.

This data has a sent string field (can be string or date-format), issue I have is I want to append a font awesome button ONLY if the field sent is an empty string " without having to create a different HTML template inside my success function.

```
$.ajax({
  async: true,
  url: '/bulletins',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'JSON',

  success: function(data) {

    $('.row[data-link=' + linked_entry + ']').remove();

    $.each(data.bulletins, function(index, item) {

      var subbed_row = '<tr class="row" data-link="subs">';
      subbed_row += '<td>' + item.title + '</td>';
      subbed_row += '<td>' + item.body + '</td>';
      subbed_row += '<td>' + item.sent + '</td>';
      subbed_row += '<td class="entry_table_options_container"><i class="fa fas fa-envelope form_show_edit" data-link="subs" data-id="' + item.id + '" data-title="' + item.title + '" data-body="' + item.body + '"  data-sent="' + item.sent + '" title="Enviar boletín a todos los subscriptores" style="background-color:#82C91E;"></i></td>';
      subbed_row += '</tr>';

      $('.entry_table_container[data-link=' + linked_entry + ']').append(subbed_row);
    });
  },

  error: function(data) {
    var errors = data.responseJSON;
    console.log(errors);
  }

});
```

This is the part I want to append or not, in case it's not empty the row would just appear without the button.

```
subbed_row += '<td class="entry_table_options_container"><i class="fa fas fa-envelope form_show_edit" data-link="subs" data-id="'+ item.id + '" data-title="'+ item.title +'" data-body="'+ item.body +'"  data-sent="'+ item.sent +'" title="Enviar boletín a todos los subscriptores" style="background-color:#82C91E;"></i></td>';
```

Comment: `+ (item.sent ? "" : "<button />")`

Answer (score 0):

The [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) is pretty useful for a small inline 'if' condition.

You use it like:

```
condition ? [result if true] : [result if false]
```

So in your case, you should be able to do something like this:

```
subbed_row += data === '' ? '<td class="entry_table_options_container"><i class="fa fas fa-envelope form_show_edit" data-link="subs" data-id="'+ item.id + '" data-title="'+ item.title +'" data-body="'+ item.body +'"  data-sent="'+ item.sent +'" title="Enviar boletín a todos los subscriptores" style="background-color:#82C91E;"></i></td>' : ''
```

If `data` is `''` then it will add the `td` string to `subbed_row`, otherwise it will add nothing (`''`).

Comment: I think this can be a better condition to check:  `(!data.trim())`